# setting function's parameter as null

Tags: javascript

please doee anyone have an idea how the first code works and the second doesn't? i saw the first code somewhere and i have been trying to understand the idea behind it. thanks

```js
const loadable = (importFunc, { fallback = null } = { fallback: null }) => {
  const LazyComponent = lazy(importFunc);

  return props => (
    <Suspense fallback={fallback}>
      <LazyComponent {...props} />
    </Suspense>
  );
};
```

Comment: Neither of the functions are valid declarations

Comment: the first code was valid, the log returned null while the second returns an error

Comment: I ran both of them in my browser's javascript console. The first one gives `SyntaxError: Invalid destructuring assignment target.` and the second one `SyntaxError: Cannot use the keyword 'null' as a parameter name.`

Comment: it ran for me, i edit my question and add the context it was used for. it was used for lazy loading it an application

Comment: i've added the original code

Answer (score 1):

When you destructure in the argument list with an object, an identifier after a colon indicates the new variable to put the property into.

This:

```
const test2 = ({ fallback: foo }) => {
  // rest of function
```

means

```
const test2 = (parameter) => {
  let foo = parameter.fallback;
  // rest of function
```

But you're not using `foo`, but `null` - which the interpreter (and specification) recognizes as almost certainly being an accidental error. You don't want to put a value into an identifier named `null`, so it prohibits you from doing so.

Neither of the codes you provided are valid syntax for this reason.

If you just want to put the `fallback` property of the argument into a variable, omit the colon.

```js
const test2 = ({ fallback }) => {
 console.log(fallback);
}
//calling
test2({fallback: "hello"});
```

If you also want to provide a default value in case the property is undefined, use `=` (not `:`).

```js
const test2 = ({ fallback = null }) => {
 console.log(fallback);
}
//calling
test2({fallback: "hello"});
test2({});
```

If you also want to provide a default value for the whole object argument in case no arguments are passed, use another `=` after the argument is listed (very similar to what you're doing originally, but, again, with `=`, not `:`)

```js
const test2 = ({ fallback = null } = {}) => {
 console.log(fallback);
}
//calling
test2({fallback: "hello"});
test2({});
test2();
```

Comment: i edited the question, the function is called without an argument, the first code returns null, which isn't an error. so i want to understand how it works

Comment: Neither of the examples are valid syntax, still, since you're doing `{ fallback: null }` and not `{ fallback = null }`.

Comment: i've added the original code

Comment: Yep, that syntax is valid - it's nearly the same as the last snippet in my answer, except that it assigns a default value *for the argument* that includes the property, in comparison to defaulting to an empty object and using a default value during destructuring instead. I'd recommend my approach because it's a bit DRYer (fewer chances of typos or copy/paste errors).

Comment: i tried your method but i am getting an error, setting {fallback = null}

Comment: What is the error? You can press **Run code snippet** to see all three snippets in my answer working without problems - I don't know what yuo're referring to.